# Parsing lines with numbers and words

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a file to parse and I don't know which is the best strategy to make the regular expression. I want to obtain the line where de data is. (I already made to get the data I want from lines, but I realised I left behind some matches because my first regular expression it is not good.)

Here is some of the regular expressions/strategies I tried:

1. Find the heading and match everything below until two blank lines:

   ```
   data_regex = re.compile("(?<=    ------- ------ -----    ------- ------ -----   ---- --  --------     -----------\n)[^(\n)^(\n)^]+")
   ```

   What it matches:

   ```
   1.3e-26   92.9  13.7    4.3e-26   91.2   8.9    2.0  2  BPD_transp_1 Binding-protein-dependent transport system inne
   4.7e-34  117.1  19.5      9e-34  116.2  13.5    1.4  1  BPD_transp_1 Binding-protein-dependent transport system inne
   3.2e-153  509.4   5.2   3.6e-153  509.2   3.6    1.0  1  IMPDH        IMP dehydrogenase / GMP reductase domain
   1.3e-20   73.2   0.2    3.4e-19   68.6   0.1    2.5  3  DEAD         DEAD/DEAH box helicase
   6.9e-11   42.1   0.0    1.8e-09   37.5   0.0    2.4  2  CTP_transf_2 Cytidylyltransferase
   ```

   As you can see it matches some data but not everything or not as I expected. But I tried with another one:

   ```
   data_regex = re.compile("(?<=    E-value  score  bias    E-value  score  bias    exp  N  Model        Description\s)(.+\s)+")
   ```

   In this expression I expected to have more than needed, ie including the --- line but I end up with this:

   ```
   3.6    7.2  11.6       0.13   11.9   3.6    2.0  2  Spore_YabQ   Spore cortex protein YabQ (Spore_YabQ)

   0.63    9.6   3.1       0.42   10.2   0.3    2.1  2  IBV_3C       IBV 3C protein

   0.38    9.6   4.8       0.65    8.9   0.8    2.6  3  PcrB         PcrB family

   0.059   12.6   0.3          1    8.6   0.0    2.8  3  DUF699       Putative ATPase (DUF699)

   0.028   14.1   0.9         14    5.7   0.0    3.8  4  HEAT         HEAT repeat
   ```

   Again, some results but not what I expected
2. Find the structure, of number separation multiple times and then words:

   ```
   data_regex = re.compile("(\s+([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)\s+)(\w+\s)+")
   ```

   But it founds many numbers and not the numbers spaces, word that I wanted:

   ```
   (' 2010 ', '2010', 'Medical ')
   (' 1 ', '1', 'domain ')
   ('    1.5  ', '1.5', '1 ')
   ('   6.2e-27      ', '6.2e-27', '12 ')
   ('      17     ', '17', '129 ')
   ('       7     ', '7', '130 ')
   (' 0.92\n\n  ', '0.92', 'each ')
   (' 5.2e-31\n                        ', '5.2e-31', 'PucR ')
   ```

I am using this to get the matches

```
data_result = re.findall(data_regex, document)
print data_result
```

The type of data I am parsing, a extract of the file:

```
# CPU time: 0.66u 0.50s 00:00:01.16 Elapsed: 00:00:00.55
# Mc/sec: 902.81
//
Query:       LD_216  [L=247]
Description: # 237337 # 238077 # 1 # ID=1_216;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=GGAG/GAGG;rbs_spacer=5-10bp;gc_cont=0.390
Scores for complete sequence (score includes all domains):
   --- full sequence ---   --- best 1 domain ---    -#dom-
    E-value  score  bias    E-value  score  bias    exp  N  Model        Description
    ------- ------ -----    ------- ------ -----   ---- --  --------     -----------
      3e-24   85.3   0.0    5.2e-24   84.5   0.0    1.4  1  ABC_tran     ABC transporter
    3.2e-11   42.5   0.3    9.7e-11   40.9   0.2    1.7  1  SMC_N        RecF/RecN/SMC N terminal domain
    3.1e-05   22.4   0.1       0.17   10.1   0.0    2.6  2  ABC_ATPase   Predicted ATPase of the ABC class
    6.5e-05   21.8   0.1     0.0001   21.2   0.0    1.3  1  DUF258       Protein of unknown function, DUF258
      0.001   19.0   0.5       0.21   11.5   0.0    2.2  2  AAA          ATPase family associated with various cellular 
     0.0019   16.4   0.1     0.0046   15.1   0.0    1.6  2  DLIC         Dynein light intermediate chain (DLIC)
     0.0032   15.8   0.1      0.028   12.7   0.0    2.0  2  Adeno_IVa2   Adenovirus IVa2 protein
  ------ inclusion threshold ------
      0.016   14.5   0.3      0.037   13.4   0.2    1.8  1  Arch_ATPase  Archaeal ATPase
      0.018   14.3   0.0      0.046   13.0   0.0    1.6  1  UPF0079      Uncharacterised P-loop hydrolase UPF0079
       0.02   13.3   0.2      0.041   12.3   0.1    1.4  1  Rad17        Rad17 cell cycle checkpoint protein
      0.026   13.7   0.1      0.049   12.8   0.0    1.4  1  PduV-EutP    Ethanolamine utilisation - propanediol utilisat
      0.046   12.2   0.0      0.085   11.4   0.0    1.5  1  GSPII_E      Type II/IV secretion system protein
       0.05   12.4   0.0      0.087   11.6   0.0    1.4  1  Mg_chelatase Magnesium chelatase, subunit ChlI
      0.054   12.0   0.2      0.094   11.2   0.2    1.7  1  NB-ARC       NB-ARC domain
      0.056   12.9   0.1       0.15   11.5   0.1    1.8  1  MobB         Molybdopterin guanine dinucleotide synthesis pr
      0.059   12.0   0.4        8.9    4.8   0.0    2.4  2  KAP_NTPase   KAP family P-loop domain
      0.079   12.3   0.3       0.57    9.5   0.1    2.1  2  AAA_5        AAA domain (dynein-related subfamily)
      0.086   11.9   0.2       0.32   10.0   0.0    2.0  2  IstB         IstB-like ATP binding protein
       0.13   11.0   1.6        3.5    6.3   0.1    2.7  3  KaiC         KaiC
       0.23   11.3   1.3       0.92    9.4   0.1    2.7  4  RNA_helicase RNA helicase


Domain annotation for each model (and alignments):
>> ABC_tran  ABC transporter


# Here begins other type of data but above there are two empty lines
```

The `------ inclusion threshold ------` line can be after the `------- ------ -----    ------- ------ -----   ---- --  --------     -----------` line or a random position . And If possible I would like to know where it matches each line as I will need to treat them different if they are included in the threshold or not.

How can I get these lines of the file?

Expected output:

```
      3e-24   85.3   0.0    5.2e-24   84.5   0.0    1.4  1  ABC_tran     ABC transporter
    3.2e-11   42.5   0.3    9.7e-11   40.9   0.2    1.7  1  SMC_N        RecF/RecN/SMC N terminal domain
    3.1e-05   22.4   0.1       0.17   10.1   0.0    2.6  2  ABC_ATPase   Predicted ATPase of the ABC class
    6.5e-05   21.8   0.1     0.0001   21.2   0.0    1.3  1  DUF258       Protein of unknown function, DUF258
      0.001   19.0   0.5       0.21   11.5   0.0    2.2  2  AAA          ATPase family associated with various cellular 
     0.0019   16.4   0.1     0.0046   15.1   0.0    1.6  2  DLIC         Dynein light intermediate chain (DLIC)
     0.0032   15.8   0.1      0.028   12.7   0.0    2.0  2  Adeno_IVa2   Adenovirus IVa2 protein

      0.016   14.5   0.3      0.037   13.4   0.2    1.8  1  Arch_ATPase  Archaeal ATPase
      0.018   14.3   0.0      0.046   13.0   0.0    1.6  1  UPF0079      Uncharacterised P-loop hydrolase UPF0079
       0.02   13.3   0.2      0.041   12.3   0.1    1.4  1  Rad17        Rad17 cell cycle checkpoint protein
      0.026   13.7   0.1      0.049   12.8   0.0    1.4  1  PduV-EutP    Ethanolamine utilisation - propanediol utilisat
      0.046   12.2   0.0      0.085   11.4   0.0    1.5  1  GSPII_E      Type II/IV secretion system protein
       0.05   12.4   0.0      0.087   11.6   0.0    1.4  1  Mg_chelatase Magnesium chelatase, subunit ChlI
      0.054   12.0   0.2      0.094   11.2   0.2    1.7  1  NB-ARC       NB-ARC domain
      0.056   12.9   0.1       0.15   11.5   0.1    1.8  1  MobB         Molybdopterin guanine dinucleotide synthesis pr
      0.059   12.0   0.4        8.9    4.8   0.0    2.4  2  KAP_NTPase   KAP family P-loop domain
      0.079   12.3   0.3       0.57    9.5   0.1    2.1  2  AAA_5        AAA domain (dynein-related subfamily)
      0.086   11.9   0.2       0.32   10.0   0.0    2.0  2  IstB         IstB-like ATP binding protein
       0.13   11.0   1.6        3.5    6.3   0.1    2.7  3  KaiC         KaiC
       0.23   11.3   1.3       0.92    9.4   0.1    2.7  4  RNA_helicase RNA helicase
```

**Edit**
I ended up changing reading the file with `readlines()` and then for each line do the following:

```
elif lines.startswith("   "):
    data_regex = re.compile("-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?")#Matches numbers
    data_result = re.findall(data_regex, lines) 
    data_regex2 = re.compile("[?!]") # Some other characters found
    data_result2 = re.findall(data_regex2, lines)
    data_regex3 = re.compile("-{2,}") # Finds where are the ----- lines
    data_result3 = re.findall(data_regex3, lines)

# There are numbers in the line and there are 10 or more words and numbers (8 numbers
# and plus id and description), and it doesn't have any "strange" character or it is
# a --- line
    if data_result != [] and len(lines.split()) >= 10 and data_result2 == [] and data_result3 == []:
        print lines[:-1]
```

Comment: I think you will likely be much better off trying to solve this without regex, using str.split() instead (which by default will split on whitespace, which matches your data).

Comment: Yes I thought the same, but then I will need to join again the description, and there are more tables which something like `" ".join(line[7::]` would work.I could do it if I could get just this data posted here, but the file contains more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this regular expressions after reading the file line to line.

```
data_regex = re.compile("^ {3,10}((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)\s*){8}.+")
```

It checks enough spaces (`{3,10}`)at the beginning of the line (`^`)to avoid other data, followed by 8 (`{8}`)numbers (`-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?`) with possible space between (`\s*`) and the rest of the line (`.+`)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. Remove all those comments, like `-----blablabla-----` and such so that you have a file with only data in columns
2. If you use `numpy`, assume that columns are separated by `tab`.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import numpy as np

   dat = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter='\t', dtype=str)
   ```

   `dat` will contain all numbers and words in 2d array with type `str`, then `dat[:,0:7]` will contain all the numbers.

Comment: I do not generate the file, and I don't want to modify. And I will need to treat different data above the `------ inclusion threshold ------` and below. And there are more tables in the file which would be affected by removing the `----`

Comment: @Llopis I got it.  But by *removing*, I mean you could output an intermediate data file with all those things removed and tables separated.  And treat each table as you want.

Comment: And how could I get that table separated? In the file there are more than 2200 table like this one.